# PySide: Adding widgets one after the other and not waiting until all have finished rendering

Tags: pyside

The example below creates a pyside window that contains 5 sub widgets. Assuming that one sub widget is quite complex and takes a bit to render (simulated with a `time.sleep(1)`). When executing the code...

### What I get:

The GUI event loop freezes until it has rendered all 5 widgets. Only then, the window will show up and all 5 custom widgets get shown at once.

### What I would like instead:

I would like to show the window --immediately-- and get all widgets added one after the other.

I have already tried running with a separate thread that emits a signal that triggers adding an element but it still takes 5 seconds until all widgets have been rendered and will only then show all widgets at once.

How can I get the window to appear immediatately and get one widget added after the other.
Note that I use heavy custom widgets in here. Using Model-View is no option, unfortunately.

#### The code:

```py
import time

from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        for i in range(6):
            widget = MySubWidget(i)
            layout.addWidget(widget)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        
class MySubWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, index):
        super(MySubWidget, self).__init__()
        self.index = index
        
        # Add a lot of widgets to make rendering the widget heavy...
        time.sleep(1)
        #######
        
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(str(index))
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        
        self.setLayout(layout)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.raise_()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: There's very little (or, fundamentally, nothing) you can do about it. All UI elements must be constructed and laid out in the main thread. While you could theoretically add them individually using a "default" size hint, the final lay out will consume lots of processes that will still need to happen in the main thread, and the result won't change a lot: this processing will freeze the UI interaction and drawing anyway, and in the end it would take it even more time to make the application actually *ready* to be used.

Comment: 1 second sounds suspicious for layouting and drawing custom widget, It should be faster, do they do something heavy on `__init__` like conecting to db or reading files or loading highres images?

Comment: What exactly is a "*heavy custom widget*"? What ***specifically*** does it do that causes the slow rendering? Have you made the effort to at least do some basic [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to see where the main bottle-necks are?

Comment: The only heavy thing that I am doing here is rendering custom widgets that contain lots and lots of sub widgets (buttons, text edits, line inputs, labels, images, etc). I am aware of model-view, but cannot really use it i efficiently in my case since I rely on very specific widgets. Sorry for the vague answer, it's unfortunately hard to break this down to a very simplified example.

Comment: Actually, I found some solution that fulfils my needs:
https://pastebin.com/6LeDzUVx

I could swear that I tried that before but it did not do what I was hoping. By enforcing a `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` (L33) this will now render one widget after the other (example slightly changed). I have read in several places that this is not best practise and could pottentially slow down processing but in my example that would be totally fine as I make this configurable and leave it to the user to decide if they want to wait on everything having loaded or if they want a continuous load.

Comment: Just to be clear, since this might have gotten into a wrong direction, rendering one widget does not take 1 second on my end, this was just for demonstration purpose to simulate a widget that is 'not instantly rendered'. It takes rather a few miliseconds. Due to rendering several hundred of these custom widgets that contain then all in all several thousand custom widgets takes a few seconds (3-6 seconds in my example). That is why I asked about continuous loading. My stated example using a `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` to release the GUI lock solves my needs perfectly.

Comment: your problem must be different  than what you described if `processEvents` was the solution.